# How can i create instance conditionally(by string) in Java?

Tags: java, interface

I'm trying to create(initiate) instance conditionally.

I have an interface and there are several classes which implement the interface.
(e.g. interface named "itfc" and there class "classA", "classB", "classC"

when I get a string from outside, (e.g. "a") then I wanna make class of A

so, it can be written like this:

```
public class someClass {
    itfc interface;

    public someClass(String name) {
         this.inteface = makeInstanceByName(name);
    }

    public makeInstanceByName(name) {
         if (name == "A") { return new classA(); }
         else if (name == "B") { return new classB(); }
         ...
         else { return null; }
    }

}
```

but I have lots of classes which implements the interface, and also this codes don't look good.

I've searched the enums, but I don't know how to apply it into my one.

Can you help me?

Comment: `interface` is a reserved keyword - call your thing something else. Also is `itfc` supposed to be a type? If so, why is it not using proper Java case conventions? It feels like you misunderstood how to declare variables type and naming here.

Comment: sorry, it was just a mistake. 
the thing is , there is a interface like ( public interface Itfc { ~ } )
and i declare this interface as "Itfc itfc". my bad

Comment: Start using proper java conventions: and interface, like a class, starts with a capital letter, and because others (including future your) need to be able to read that code, spell it out. "ltfc" is nothing, it's not a word, it's not a description, etc. Write a proper interface name, and then declare a field of that type. And _update your code in the post_ to actually show the relevant code you're using, don't slim it down to the point where it has syntax errors.

Comment: ok, thank you. i'm newbie in programming, especially in java, and also english is not my first language so i'm not used to the things you mentioned. i would do write better in future questions. thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [`class.forName(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName-java.lang.String-), e.g. something like

```java
Class.forName("my.package.name.ClassPrefix" + name)
```

Also make sure you take care of proper exception handling.

---

**Update:** Here is a complete [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as a proof of concept which also shows you how to instantiate the class via reflection API. But in this case you need to make sure that each target class has a default (no-arguments) constructor.

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public interface MyInterface {}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class Foo implements MyInterface {}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class Bar implements MyInterface {}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class Zot implements MyInterface {}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class UhOh /*implements MyInterface*/ {}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class Application {
  public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {
    System.out.println(makeInstanceByName("Foo"));
    System.out.println(makeInstanceByName("Bar"));
    System.out.println(makeInstanceByName("Zot"));
    System.out.println(makeInstanceByName("UhOh"));
  }

  public static MyInterface makeInstanceByName(String name) throws Exception {
    return
      (MyInterface) Class.forName("de.scrum_master.app." + name)
        .getConstructor()
        .newInstance();
  }
}
```

Console log:

```
de.scrum_master.app.Foo@6d06d69c
de.scrum_master.app.Bar@7852e922
de.scrum_master.app.Zot@4e25154f
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: de.scrum_master.app.UhOh cannot be cast to de.scrum_master.app.MyInterface
    at de.scrum_master.app.Application.makeInstanceByName(Application.java:15)
    at de.scrum_master.app.Application.main(Application.java:8)
```

Comment: **Update:** I have added an interface and a negative test case to the solution.